# How to print sub JSON values using Python

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file that has this structure:

```
{
  "USD" : {"15m" : 6650.3, "last" : 6650.3, "buy" : 6650.3, "sell" : 6650.3, "symbol" : "$"},
  "AUD" : {"15m" : 10857.19, "last" : 10857.19, "buy" : 10857.19, "sell" : 10857.19, "symbol" : "$"},
  "BRL" : {"15m" : 33997.0, "last" : 33997.0, "buy" : 33997.0, "sell" : 33997.0, "symbol" : "R$"},
}
```

At the moment, my Python code prints out all of the AUD section. I would like to however only print out the 15m value.

My code is as follows (the link in bitcoin_api_url variable contains the JSON file request):

```
import requests

bitcoin_api_url = 'https://blockchain.info/ticker'

response = requests.get(bitcoin_api_url)
response_json = response.json()

print(response_json["AUD"])
```

I would appreciate any help, or point in the right direction (i.e. documentation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print(response_json["AUD"]["15m"])`

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried doing this for some reason: print(response_json["AUD"["15m"]])

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests

bitcoin_api_url = 'https://blockchain.info/ticker'

response = requests.get(bitcoin_api_url)
response_json = response.json()

print(response_json["AUD"]["15m"])
```